# CURL PHP HEADER DATA

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am trying to use [jobcrank](http://api.jobcrank.com/v2/QueryService.asmx?op=QueryJob) feeds api and it requires data to be sent in headers
I want to make request in the following format

```
POST /v2/QueryService.asmx/QueryJob HTTP/1.1
Host: api.jobcrank.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: length
```

and the query parameters will be sent in following method

```
apiKey=string&apiSerial=string&serviceTypeID=string&jobType=string&keyWordsType=string&keyWords=string&stateAbbreviation=string&county=string&city=string&isWorkFromHome=string
```

I have written code also for this but dont know how to send header containing 
"POST /v2/QueryService.asmx/QueryJob HTTP/1.1" line
Here is my code:`

```
<?php
        $fields = array(
    'apiKey'=>'XXX',
    'apiSerial'=>'XXXX',);
$fields_string="";
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string,'&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'/v2/QueryService.asmx/QueryJob');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CURLOPT_URL` requires an absolute URL with scheme and host:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.org/v2/QueryService.asmx/QueryJob');
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set this header - it is being done automatically. What you however need to do is to urlencode your `$fields_string`, because it may contain forbidden characters like white space. To do this, use `http_build_query` to build this string directly from your array:

```
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

It will urlencode the values and make the valid post string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to explicitly add POST header. Curl will do that for you, just set `CURLOPT_POST` flag to true and that is it.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
```

Have a look at this site when in doubt: http://php.net/curl_setopt